# query pattern not found in Join query for lightswitch when using LINQ

Tags: linq, join, visual-studio-lightswitch

```
var accState = from obj in this.DataWorkspace.FF_DataExtractData.stg_auto_operators
               join avo in this.DataWorkspace.FF_DataExtractData.stg_auto_veh_oper_assns on obj.etl_sequence_number equals avo.operator_seq_nbr
               join pu in this.DataWorkspace.FF_DataExtractData.punits on avo.operator_seq_nbr equals pu.c59_id
               select pu.a02_state;
```

**Error:** **Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.Framework.EntitySet'.  'Join' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'obj'.**

i want the value of state through this LINQ,

operator_seq_nbr, c59_id and etl_sequenceNumber are of LONG type,

a02_state is of string type.

Answer (score 0):

Lightswitch only allows you to return complete entities as the result of queries, you can't reshape the data. So selecting a single field (pu.a02_state in this case) isn't valid. The logical extension of not being able to reshape is that JOIN isn't valid either since that exists to allow you to combine fields from different entities.

You can return a set of entities that match your criteria using Lambda syntax. But your query doesn't have any selection criteria even though it seems like you're expecting a single value to be returned. Can you clarify the data and intent a little?

Comment: in the table, stg_auto_operator, i want to use the field etl_sequence_number (LONG), which is related to Operator_sequence_number in table(stg_auto_veh_oper_assns). 

stg_auto_veh_oper_assns has field Pv_id which is related to c59_id in table (PUnit),   Punit has a coulumn (a02_state) which i want corresponding to c59_id.

Comment: Hi Jatin, That's just a description of the query, which I can read. But how many entities are you expecting to return - one or many? Are there any selection criteria - i.e. are you looking for the state value for a particular entity? Can you provide some sample data? Phil